# PHPUnit suppress Ignored messages

Tags: php, phpunit

Is there a way of suppressing the messages printed to the cli

For example we have a few tests which are waiting for PHPUnit 5.5.* (which we plan to update to soon).  But each of these tests print out

`PHPUnit 5.5 (or later) is required.`

Is there a cli command to filter these out?  I couldn't find one here https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/textui.html

**EDIT:**
The command being run is just `phpunit --configuration /path/to/config.xml`

Which look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
     backupStaticAttributes="false"
     bootstrap="site-config.php"
     colors="true"
     convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
     convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
     convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
     processIsolation="false"
     stopOnFailure="false">
  <testsuites>
    <testsuite name="Application Test Suite">
        <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests</directory>
    </testsuite>
  </testsuites>
  <filter>
    <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
        <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>
        <directory suffix=".php">./classes</directory>
    </whitelist>
  </filter>
</phpunit>
```

**In response to a comment:**
The warnings are definitely from PHPUnit, they're in as a result from using `@requires` from the 'Skipped/Incomplete Test' documentation: 
https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/incomplete-and-skipped-tests.html

Comment: What command are you running? What deps are being used along with phpunit (`composer info` might help)? Are you sure that message is coming from phpunit?

Comment: Sorry meant to come back.  These messages are definitely from PHPUnit, see edits to question.  I can still include the composer information if need be, but don't think it's relevant.  It's to do with phpunit itself and whether a feature exists

Answer (score 0):

It must have `verbose="true"` in your phpunit.xml, because the PHPUnit don't print [verbose](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/bb24734/src/TextUI/ResultPrinter.php#L167) message by default. Check the following commands to see the different.

```
$ phpunit --no-configuration /path/to/tests/dir

PHPUnit 5.7.27 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

S                                                1 / 1 (100%)

Time: 93 ms, Memory: 6.00MB

OK, but incomplete, skipped, or risky tests!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Skipped: 1.
```

-

```
$ phpunit --verbose --no-configuration /path/to/tests/dir

PHPUnit 5.7.27 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

S                                                 1 / 1 (100%)

Time: 93 ms, Memory: 6.00MB

There was 1 skipped test:

1) ExampleTest::testPHPUnitRequire
PHPUnit >= 7.2 is required.

OK, but incomplete, skipped, or risky tests!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Skipped: 1.
```